# Continuity of the function defined by: $f(x)=e^x$ if $x$ is rational; $f(x)=e^{1-x}$ if $x$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let the function $f(x)$ be defined as

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
      e^x & x\text{ is rational} \\   e^{(1-x)} & x\text{ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$

for $x$ in $(0,1)$. Then

a. $f$ is continuous at every point in $(0,1)$

b. $f$ is discontinuous at every point in $(0,1)$

c. $f$ is  discontinuous only at one point in $(0,1)$

d. $f$ is  continuous  only at one point in $(0,1)$

the correct answer for this is the option d. Can anyone tell me what is that one point at which it's continuous?  According to me - it's not continuous .

Comment: What do you think about where $e^x=e^{1-x}$. Could you find such a point? Could you draw a picture and see how this might work?

Comment: I agree: This one is pretty obvious from the picture.

Comment: yeah I know that..but I dint get any point where its equal..between the given intervals@ Jp McCarthy

Comment: @amit How about $x=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: oohhh..yes... :)

Answer (score 2):

it is only continuous at x=0.5  because 
$$\begin{cases}
 & \text{ if } x= \frac{1}{2} \rightarrow e^x=e^{\frac{1}{2}} (\frac{1}{2}     \in Q) \\ 
 & \text{ if } x\rightarrow    (\frac{1}{2}     \in Q^C) \rightarrow e^{1-x} \rightarrow e^{1/2}
\end{cases} $$ 
but in other points it is not continuous because

suppose f is continuous at every points of this interval 
so $$e^{x}=e^{1-x} \\e^x=e*\frac{1}{e^x}\\e^{2x}=e^1\\2x=1\\x=\frac{1}{2}$$so this not continuous at every point (but  in x=1/2)

Comment: thanyou..sorry..I dint thought of this..

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of the function $f(x)$ around the point $x = \frac 1 2$ is interesting. To examine it in some detail, let us take a small interval around this point: $(\frac 1 2 - \delta, \frac 1 2 + \delta)$ with delta an arbitrarily small number. Now if you consider the function $f(x)$ in this interval, you will see that -however small delta is chosen- it still behaves completely erratically: nearly everywhere it is jumping up and down between the values $e^x$ and $e^{1-x}$.

This might suggest that the function is also discontinuous in this case.... However, that is not true. Because we must also take into account the magnitude of these jumps. These are given by $|e^{x}-e^{1-x}|$. Now it turns out that -in the given interval- all jumps are smaller than or equal to $e^{\frac 1 2}(e^{\delta}-e^{-\delta})$. This upper bound is practically equal to $2e^{\frac 1 2}\delta$. This means that in the limit of $\delta \rightarrow 0$, the magnitude of the jumps also goes to zero. Therefore, by definition, the continuity of the function f has been established at $x = \frac 1 2$.

Answer (score 0):

For all $x_0\in (0,1)$, and if $f$ is continous at $x_0$, then it needs two conditions, 1)$\lim_{x\to x_o}f(x)$ must exists 2)$\lim_{x\to x_o}f(x)=f(x_0)$.

First we check whether $\lim_{x\to x_o}f(x)$ exists, this is equivalent to
$$\lim_{x\to x_o, x\in \mathbb{Q}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_o, x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}f(x)$$
Hence we must have $e^{x_0}=e^{1-x_0}\iff x_0=\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence we know $f$ is not continuous at $(0,1)\setminus\{\frac{1}{2}\}$ Then we check whether it's continuous at $\frac{1}{2}$. Indeed it is, since $\lim_{x\to x_o, x\in \mathbb{Q}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_o, x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{2}}=f(\frac{1}{2})$. So the function is continuous at $\frac{1}{2}$ and discontinuous at $(0,1)\setminus\{\frac{1}{2}\}$.